# Define range for match with column number

Tags: microsoft-excel

I can't find a way to dynamically define the lookup-array C:C for MATCH formula:

```
=MATCH(A1,C:C,0)
```

I need to define the "C:C" range by using the **numeric values for the columns** (column C is 3).

Already tried converting the number to char and using it in the formula but it doesn't work:

```
=MATCH(A1,CHAR(3+64),0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
=MATCH(A2,INDEX(A:Z,0,3),0)
```

Where 3 is the column number.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do an indirect evaluation of the concatenated string that evaluates to `C:C`

The formula that works for me is

```
=MATCH(A1,INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(CHAR(3+64),":",CHAR(3+64))),0)
```

Where

```
CONCATENATE(CHAR(3+64),":",CHAR(3+64))
```

gives the result of `C:C` and

```
INDIRECT(value)
```

Evaluates the string you constructed using the [CONCATENATE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CONCATENATE-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d) function.

> [INDIRECT(ref_text, [a1])](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261)
>
> - Returns the reference specified by a text string. References are immediately evaluated to display their contents. Use INDIRECT when you want to change the reference to a cell within a formula without changing the formula itself.

Comment: Thanks! this works perfect. For the CHAR(3+64) I used this instead:

`=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,3,4),"1","")`
(where 3 is the column number)

so the formula works double letter columns (after Z)